# Facebook read_stream API 1.0

Tags: facebook

I know that Facebook disable read_stream permission with API 2.x.

But I have a app created with API V1.0 (reviewed but without read_stream). If I add /me/home I need to resubmit the app? or with API V1.0 I can use it?

Best,

Comment: If your app was created and active before 4/30/2014 you can use read_stream until 4/30/2015. Why you want to create an app that will break in less then 6 months I don't know

Comment: @WizKid But I need to re-submit the app to review with Facebook?

Comment: If your app can use API v1.0 you don't need to submit to use a permission